# No php.ini file

Tags: web, download, fopen, php

I'm making a PHP form that requests a file for download. I've had an error with the script and did some searching found out that it was because my php.ini file needed `allow_url_fopen = On`, so I went to change the settings and my site has no php.ini file. I couldn't really find out how to make a php.ini file. How would I create this file? My web host says I need to create it. What are the default settings to put into this file?

Comment: Where did you look for the file?  Depending on what host you're using it could be in a number of places.

Comment: First of all, it depends on the platform you are developing on. php.ini files can also be fetched from subdirectories, when using an Apache2 webserver, in that case, it will only overwrite defined values.

Answer (score 4):

- First, try to figure out, whether you really don't have the file. The php.ini location can be found in [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)(); output.
- Second, if there is such file, edit that one. If not, download the ZIP package from php.net and there is at least [php.ini.recommended](http://fts.ifac.cnr.it/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/php5/examples/php.ini-recommended), which contains basic directives.

Comment: In PHP 5.6 I couldn't find a php.ini.recommended file. I found php.ini-production and php.ini-production and php.ini-development. I used one of those and just changed the extention. It worked

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have no php.ini file, you can create it with as few lines in it as you need.  Just put `allow_url_fopen = On` on an ascii file and name it php.ini, copy it to the working directory or the public root. Take in mind that anyway this values can be overrided by hosting's staff in places where you do not have access. To see what is the final and actual setting that aplies use phpinfo().
A side note: .htaccess files can in some circunstances govern and override php settings, so also take a look on all of them (that are accesible to you) to see if you can set your preferences there.  Be careful that systax differs from php.ini [.htaccess example](http://support.tigertech.net/php-value)